# How to sum tuples in a list of tuples?

Tags: list, haskell, map-function

I have the following list for example:

```
example = [(5.4, 3.2), (2.4, 3.5), (2.4, 4.0), (5.1, 3.6)]
```

And I'd like to get the sum of each '()' tuple. It means that I'd like to sum 5.4 with 3.2, then 2.4 with 3.5 and so on.

The result should look like this:

```
First: 8.6
Second: 5.9
Third: 6.4
Fourth: 8.7
```

I could do it with one pair only, but don't know how to get each sum from the list.

```
sumexample:: [(Double, Double)] -> [Double]
sumexample [(a, b)] = a + b
```

Comment: Hint: write a function for summing only one pair. Then use it in another function which scans the whole list (using recursion, or `map`).

Comment: So you say my 'sumexample' is good but I need to use this function in another one?

Comment: I can't find any example for the second function. Could you show me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you wrote

```
sumexample :: [(Double, Double)] -> [Double]
sumexample [(a, b)] = [ a + b ]
  --                 ^^^     ^^^     -- (error, corrected)
```

Ah, great! You've already got all you need to solve it. Almost. The missing part is the appending operator `++`, with which a list of any length can be built by appending the singleton lists of its elements:

```
[  1,     2,     3,    ...  ] ===
  [1] ++ [2] ++ [3] ++ ...
```

So then `sumexampleList` should follow the law of

```
sumexampleList :: [(Double, Double)] -> [Double]
sumexampleList   [a  ,                  b  ,              c  ,  ... ]   ===
sumexampleList ( [a] ++                [b] ++            [c] ++ ...   ) ===
      sumexample [a] ++ sumexample     [b] ++ sumexample [c] ++ ...     ===
      sumexample [a] ++ sumexampleList [b,                c,    ... ] 
      --                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   --- right?
```

Haskell doesn't understand the above as a valid definitional syntax though. But it does understand

```
[1,   2,  3,  ...] ===
 1 : [2,  3,  ...]
```

and so we can re-write the above law in the conventional syntax as

```
sumexampleList (a : bcde) =
   sumexample a ++ sumexampleList bcde
```

and that is a bona fide recursive function definition in Haskell.
One case is missing though, the one with the empty list, `[]`.

You will need to complete the definition by adding that additional equation.

---

Having solved this, `sumexample :: [(Double, Double)] -> [Double]` is bad design: it only works with singletons, but the type is *list*. So do away with the brackets altogether:

```
sumexample :: (Double, Double) -> Double
sumexample (a, b) = ....
```

and amend the recursive definition accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: it's alright, any response is better than no response. and you're welcome. :) BTW, this recursive function follows a certain computational pattern, applying a function to each element of a list and collecting back the results -- IOW, transforming each element of a list through some function -- IOW transforming a *list* of elements using an *element*-transforming function. this is known as `map` for lists, or `fmap` in general for any data structure that supports this (which thus is known as an instance of "`Functor`" "pattern"). See the tag that I added to the question. So then,

Comment: using `map`, this can be just written as `map g` where `g (a,b) = ....`. there's another concept, [tag:currying], (with the pair of functions `curry f a b = f (a,b)` and `uncurry g (a,b) = g a b`), and then it is just `map (uncurry (+))`. So Haskell has tools which already capture lots of these kind of simpler computational patterns, so we can write short code using them. But while we learn it is good to write out all these functions by hand. Cheers,